# Big foreach freeze DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a script that processes lines from a text file and sends it to the server. The server, meanwhile, returns a response and fills in the required information.
The problem is that when you try to download a file with about a million entries, the browser freezes and takes a very long time to process.
Is it possible to make this process without browser delays?

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    $('#uploader-after').show();
    $('#uploader-before').hide();
    $("#file").prop('disabled', true);
    var o_time = performance.now();
    $('o_total').text("");
    $('o_errors').text("");
    $('o_time').text("");

    var file = this.files[0];
    var count = 1;
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('.file-name').text(file.name);
    var reader = new FileReader(file);
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        $('#find-count').text(lines.length);

        for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
            //setTimeout( function() { // i try this, but dont work
                jQuery.ajax({
                    'async': true,
                    'global': false,
                    'type': "POST",
                    'url': 'getFile.php',
                    'data': { url: lines[line] },
                    'dataType': "json",
                    'success': function(data) {
                        var answer = data.answer ? data.answer : "";
                        var id = data.id ? data.id : "";

                        $('#proc-count').text(count);
                        var proc = Math.round(count / lines.length * 100);
                        $('proc').text(proc);
                        $("#pg-bar-line").css("width", proc + "%");
                        count++;

                        if(id == "") {
                            errorCount++;
                        }

                        $('o_total').text(count - 1);
                        $('o_errors').text(errorCount);

                        scannert.DataTable().row.add([id, data.inputURL, answer]).draw(false);

                        if(count === lines.length) {
                            o_time = performance.now() - o_time;
                            $('o_time').text(msToTime(o_time));
                            $('.otchet').show();

                            $('#uploader-after').hide();
                            $('#uploader-before').show();
                            $("#file").prop('disabled', false);
                        }
                    },
                    'error': function() {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            //}, 5);
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Ill try setTimeout, but it doesnt work -_-

Comment: In the case you describe you're attempting to send 1 million HTTP requests to your server in a very short space of time. Unless you've hired an entire server farm from Google or Amazon that's never going to work. A far better idea is to upload the file to the server and process it there, ideally offloading the actual task of processing to another service which isn't hosted on the webserver as processing that much data will cause you bottlenecks and massively hinder overall performance.

Comment: Your best bet is to either reduce the file size, or use the post function to grab the file and do the file processing on the backend. You can even run that asynch